# findByIdAndUpdate() method does not update the collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

So, I'm trying to update a product with mongodb and redux, but when I try to update the product, the database doesn't seem to change. I can't solve this, please can you help me?

Below I have my product.js file:

```
//UPDATE

router.put('/:id', verifyTokenAndAdmin, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const updatedProduct = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      {
        $set: req.body,
      },
      { new: true }
    );
    res.status(200).json(updatedProduct);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

apiCalls.js:

```
export const updateProducts = async (id, product, dispatch) => {
  dispatch(updateProductStart());
  try {
    const res = await userRequest.put(`/products/${id}`);
    dispatch(updateProductSuccess({ id, product }));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(updateProductFailure());
  }
};
```

requestMethods.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/';
const TOKEN =
  JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('persist:root')).user).currentUser
    .accessToken || '';

// set token
localStorage.setItem('ACCESS_TOKEN', TOKEN);

// get token
const myToken = localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN');

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const userRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  headers: { token: `Bearer ${myToken}` },
});
```

Comment: And `req.body` is correct?

Comment: Yes, I think it's correct.

Comment: Try logging `req.params.id` and then `req.body` to be sure.

Comment: Hello, I tried `console.log(req.body)`, but it returns an empty object.

Comment: @yousoumar, why do you think this happens?

Comment: And what about `req.params.id`, are you able to log it?

Comment: About `body`, it doesn't seem like you are sending any body in `apiCalls.js`.

Comment: `req.params.id` works

Comment: So how should I send it?

Comment: Can you edit your code and show `userRequest` with its `put` method? And also your express root file?

Comment: I added index.js file, is anything else you want me to send?

Comment: Thanks. Now can you show userRequest with its put method? That's where you should change to send the body. The backend seem okay.

Comment: Is it ok now? I added requestMethods.js

Comment: I pasted an answer. Give it a try and let met know in the comment section  of the answer itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `updateProducts` as below. Notice there is a second parameter given to `put`. This would be equal to `req.body` in the backend part.

```
export const updateProducts = async (id, product, dispatch) => {
  dispatch(updateProductStart());
  try {
    const res = await userRequest.put(`/products/${id}`, product);
    dispatch(updateProductSuccess({ id, product }));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(updateProductFailure());
  }
};
```

And in the backend try changing `findByIdAndUpdate` as below. And before log `req.body` to see if you are getting the data.

```
const updatedProduct = await Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body);
```